# Make a darker box in a canvas with pattern

Tags: css

I have defined a rule for `has-pattern` in my CSS:

```
.has-pattern {
  background-image: url('../images/patterns/pattern-1.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}
```

As a result, a section where `has-pattern` is applied (`<section class="team section has-pattern">`) has the following background:

[image]

Now, I want to insert a smaller box inside this section, with a darker background color. My question is how to NOT make the darker box break the existing pattern.

I tried to add the follows in my CSS:

```
.team .box-inner {
    padding: 60px;
    background-color: #3FA07A;
    background-image: url('../images/patterns/pattern-1.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

The problem is that the pattern of the two levels does not match:

[image]

Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this by not using a pattern for the inner box but by using an rgba colour value instead, allowing the pattern to show through the transparency. Eg. `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);`

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/xudg5d93/

For futher control on how the transparency affects things, you might want to look at the CSS `filter` attribute as well: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the square with black color and set `opacity` :)
edit:
example:

```css
div{
    background-color: #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;   
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
   <div><img/></div>
```

As you see, i set color for black. With opacity it change color.
When you add this for you background img, you will see effect :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`background-color: rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()).

Specify required [rgb](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) color values and adjust the opacity [***0.3*** in this example. Actual range 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque)] as required to get the desired effect.

```css
.has-pattern {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdlyZm.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px 10%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: rgba(54, 125, 94, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<section class="has-pattern">
  <div class="header">
    Heading here !
  </div>
</section>
```